# Porting WinRT to UWP

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app, porting

I have a WinRT UniversalApp in the store. Now I had made a Windows 10 project and ported all files to this project. If I push a release build to the phone with the store app installed than I get a duplicate in the app list. I have changed the mp:PhoneIdentity in the Package.Appxmanifest of the UWP app to the same values of the WinRT Phone Project. 
Is there more to do or is there something wrong?

thx newone

Comment: Well, that's because it really *is* the same.  UWP is just a new marketing term, it is still WinRT.  You target version 1.4 in a UWP app, adds a bunch of apis, but since you didn't change any code the program isn't different.  So this isn't very useful.  If you want to do this anyway then I suppose you have to increment the appxmanifest version number so it sees it as an update.

Comment: only to icrement the version number does not help

Answer (score 1):

Project->Store->Associate App with the Store

Comment: If you have an app in the store, you can associate it with the project in Visual Studio. So you will not see the duplicate.
On top menu you can find Project, then you must to sign in with the dev account and link your project with the app in the store.

Comment: I tested it and when I push a release version to the phone then Visual Studio warns me that the old version is uninstalled and new installed. Is thatthe same if I update the store version?